# What is the difference between the TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault and the new TelemetryConfiguration()?

Tags: c#, azure, constructor, default, appinsights

What is the difference between the `TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault` and the `new TelemetryConfiguration()`?

I am talking about the types from the `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility` namespace. Both seem to work the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the `TelemetryConfiguration()` then you have to manually set the `ConnectionString` property, but the `TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault()` factory method loads the `ApplicationInsights.config` file if it exists and some defaults.